# como posso inserir múltiplos linhas uma vez só usando Sql?

Tags: sql-server

Exportei um registro de dados do Sqlite para Sql Server com Dump. Preciso pegar esses registros e inserir dentro de uma nova tabela que eu criei para receber esses registros dentro do meu banco de dados no Sql server. O problema é que tenho muitos linhas para inserir.Há mais de 1.000 linhas e gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira mais simples de fazer isso que repetir 1000 vezes os insert into nomeDaTabela values...

ex:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ("John", 123, "Lloyds Office");
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ("Jane", 124, "Lloyds Office");
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ("Billy", 125, "London Office");
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ("Miranda", 126, "Bristol Office");
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ("John", 123, "Lloyds Office");
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ("roger", 23, "Nuvens");
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ("jose", 500, "London Office");
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ("elanda", 126, "Paris");
```

Vamos imaginar que esses insert tem mais de 1.000
será que há como fazer de um jeito mais fácil sem repetir 1.000 vezes?

aqui está um print de como está os registros:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi, vc tem o dump do sql lite com os insert ou não?

Comment: De onde vem as informações? Excel? Outra tabela?

Comment: Esses registros estavam no sqlite.fizemos um conversão para sql server. precisava criar um banco no sql server e gravar esses dados que estavam no Sqlite dentro do Sql server. @rray

Comment: coloque como os dados estão atualmente, seja csv ou xml

Comment: aproveita que tá no notepad++ e faz um macro alterando o texto pra sua necessidade, mais simples...

Comment: @RovannLinhalis um macro?? não entendi o que é rsrs desculpa.

Comment: Você tem o sql management (ssms) instalado? não é só copiar esses inserts colar e dar um F5 para executar todos de um vez?

Comment: entendi...sim eu poderia até mas tiver que inserir mais um covert(varbinary(max) para  converter imagem então fiz direito para não ter mais trabalho depois.so que eu devo fazer isso para todas as linhas

Comment: @rray quero acreditar que esse seja o dump do sqllite e esteja com estrutura diferente do sql server, não é possível... rs  Gladiador... usar macros no np++ : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQaxDeCwMRg

Comment: Já deu pra entender melhor o problema agora ... se for para colocar essa função em cima de algum valor pode tentar usar o modo coluna do np++ ou um pouco de regex :D

Comment: @rray salvou meu dia cara hahaha valeu.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis agora entendi o que você quis dizer com Macro no notepad++ isso também funcionou bem que dá um pouco de trablho.VALEU por ajudar, valeu mesmo!!

Comment: disponha. Não esquece de postar como foi resolvido seu problema para encerrar a questão

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então pessoal com a ajuda de vocês consegui resolver esse mistério. para substituir no lugar certo, tive que usar uma expressão regular pelo site https://regex101.com/ testar se ele conseguiria achar exatamente a onde eu deveria fazer meu replace. A minha expressão regular no meu caso foi VALUES .*, ([0-9]{5}), de 5 digitos.' [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois que ele achou eu só substitui com valores que eu queria em uma linha e  Usei o macro do Notepad++ como foi recomendado por alguém aqui para repetir a mesma ação para todas as linhas e depois jogar no sql e executar os registros e inserir no banco.

Answer (score 3):

Existe sim alguns meios mais simples de copiar esses dados:

**Linked Server**
Pode fazer um linked server do servidor de origem no servidor de destino. Desta forma poderá fazer um insert baseado em um select.

**Importação de dados**
Pode importar os dados pelo *wizard* do sql server, clicando com o botão direito no banco de dados de destino, vá em tarefas e importar dados, como na figura a seguir
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Editar manualmente os registros na tabela**
Ainda existe a possibilidade de clicar com o botão direito na tabela de destino no object explorer e clicar no item "Editar 200 linhas superiores". Com esta opção a tabela abrirá como num excel. E será possível colar os registros caso os mesmos estejam na área de transferência (tanto como origem em um grid, resultado de select ou um excel).

Comment: eu vou tentar fazer desse jeito agora depois te falo. fico grato por você ter respondido :)

Comment: As importações de dados aceitam diversos tipos de origem e conexões de dados.

Comment: @Gladiador, funcionou? Se sim, marque a resposta como uma resposta válida para a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Vá no seu sqlite é faça uma consulta que gere as querys:

```
select 'insert into ..... values ('+Campo+','..... from sua tabela....
```

O resultado deve ter o 'script de carga'

Outra opção é exportar a estrutura do banco usando o [SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/), usando a opção [Export to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163079/exporting-from-sqlite-to-sql-server).

**EDIT**

Você pode usar o o resultado de um select para incluir registros numa tabela:

```
insert into tabela values select campos from tabela.....
```

Comment: essa parte de exportar a estrutura ja foi feito.E me gerou um monte de insert. Agora precisa só inserir esses dados exportados dentro de uma nova tabela no Sql.