# Gerar script com insert das tabelas no sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, script

Uso Sql Server 2012. Fiz uma consulta com o título acima e não trouxe nada na pesquisa. Tenho um BD e necessito levá-lo para outro lugar. Logo, a melhor forma é gerar um script de todos os objetos existentes nele e como possuo tabelas populadas, preciso gerar também um script de `insert`. Como eu faço isso, o script de `insert`?

Comment: Recomendo utilizar uma ferramenta de migração que fará de forma rápida e sem erro. Já utilizei esta para MySQL, mas ela tem opção para SQL Server também. https://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-sql-server

Comment: Você precisa que o seu backup seja um *script* com instruções de `insert into`? Ou pode ser um arquivo de backup normal?

Comment: Então, tenho um cliente que eu estava com ele e precisava de dados do BD dele para eu fazer os testes de um APP que desenvolvi. O cara em alguns minutos, usando o Sql Management gerou os scripts de DDL e DML. Rápido e não consegui acompanhar para ver como ele faz. Tentei falar com ele agora e ele não está na unidade, está viajando e visitando as filiais(sul de são paulo). Sei que dá, mas não sei como. Estou pesquisando na net, mas até agora não achei. Vou para o SOen e ver se encontro por lá.

Comment: Dá uma olhada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526461/converting-select-results-into-insert-script

Comment: Dê uma olhada também nesta questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/232312/como-posso-inserir-m%C3%BAltiplos-linhas-uma-vez-s%C3%B3-usando-sql/232320#232320

Comment: Dá sim pra fazer isso por dentro do Management Studio, o problema é que fica muito lerdo quando o banco tem muitos dados, o ideal é gerar um arquivo normal de backup, é mais rápido e não tem erro.

Comment: É mixaria meu banco. Só tem 10 tabelas e apenas 3 estão populadas. Estou começando agora a desenvolver e preciso migrar. Posso até começar tudo de novo, mas gostaria de aprender a fazer isso.

Comment: Caso deseje criar somente os Inserts para uma tabela já existente basta usar o Data Only, não precisando usar o Schema and Data. Assim o script fica mais limpo. Eu uso para migrar dados de homologação para produção.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entre no Management Studio e clique com o botão direito em cima do banco a ser exportado.

Acesse o menu Tasks > Generate Scripts conforme imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vai abrir um wizard. Você escolhe o que tipo de dados você quer exportar (tabelas, views, functions...) e avança.

Na segunda etapa você clica em "avançado" e muda o item "type of data to script" para "schema and data", senão o script vai gerar a estrutura do banco mas não vai inserir o dados! Ver imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora basta você ir dando next no wizard e ele vai gerar o arquivo na sua pasta "Documentos" (ou o lugar que você selecionar).

Comment: Faltou eu escolher o typo de dados, que por default aparece apenas Schema, mas é Schema and Data.